# Global Sections of Pullback of Tautological Line Bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be an Gorenstein(so the dualizing sheaf 
$\omega_{C}$ is  invertible),

integral curve (therefore $1$-dimensional, proper $k$-scheme over a fixed field), $\mathcal{L} \in Pic(C)$ ample,

$f: C \to \mathbb{P}^n _k$ a proper morphism induced via $\mathcal{L}:=f^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$ and the image

$C' := f(C) =  im(f) \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ an integral curve of $\mathbb{P}^n$.

We can factorise $f$ als $C \xrightarrow{f'} C'  \xrightarrow{\iota} \mathbb{P}^n$. By definition we have $\mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) := \iota^* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$.

My question is why $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)) \cong H^0(C', \mathcal{O}_{C'}(1)) \cong H^0(C, \mathcal{L})$ holds?

Comment: The technical issue is what do you mean by `morphism induced via'? If you mean the map induced using $H^0(\mathcal{L})$, this is trivial. But if you just mean that the map has the property $\mathcal{L}=f^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$, then it is trivially false,

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something. $\mathcal{L}$ must be ample. Then it induces a morphism $f: C \to \mathbb{P}^n$ since $\mathbb{P}^n$ represents following functor $$F: (Sch/R) \to (Set),$$ $$X \mapsto \{(\mathcal{L},s) \vert \mathcal{L} \text{ invertible sheaf on } X, s := (s_0, s_1, ... , s_n): \mathcal{O}_X ^{\oplus n+1} \to \mathcal{L}, s \text{ surjective}\} / \cong$$

Comment: So under the condition that $\mathcal{L}$ ample, I mean that $f$ has the property $\mathcal{L}=f^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$

Comment: @Mohan: could you explain why this is trivial? Of course, $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)) \cong H^0(C, \mathcal{L})$, but what about $C'$?

Comment: Please check that your definition implies there are maps $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))\to H^0(C',i^*(\mathbb{P}^n}(1))\to H^0(C,\mathcal{L})$ and the composite is an isomorphism and the second is injective to finish the proof.

Comment: @danneks: Why $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)) \cong H^0(C, \mathcal{L})$ holds? Well, if you have this then Mohan's argument indeed provides that the injection $H^0(C', \mathcal{O}_{C'}(1)) \to H^0(C, \mathcal{L})$ is also surjective.

Comment: @Mohan: How do you get concretely the map $$H^0(C',i^*(\mathbb{P}^n(1)) \to H^0(C,\mathcal{L})$$? I tried it in following way: Starting with exact sequence $$0 \to \mathcal{O}_{C'} \to f'_*(\mathcal{O}_{C'}) \to \mathcal{F} \to 0$$ (since $f$, then also $f'$ are birational, therefore the structuresheaf is injective, $\mathcal{F} $ is the cokernel and it's a skyscraper, since birational morphism maps dense.

Comment: Then, tensoring by $\mathcal{O}_{C'}(1)$ I get the sequence 
$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) \to f'_*(\mathcal{O}_{C'}) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) \to \mathcal{F}  \to 0$$
right term has this shape because skyscraper.
My problem is to see $f'_*(\mathcal{O}_{C'}) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) \cong f'_*(\mathcal{L})$...

Comment: About $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))\cong H^0(C, \mathcal{L})$. Note that a sheaf itself does not induce a morphism to $\mathbb P^n$. You should also choose $n+1$ generating sections. You can simply take a basis of global sections, then trivially $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)) \cong H^0(C, \mathcal{L})$ (the dimension of both spaces is the same).

Comment: For any morphism $f:X\to Y$, a global section of a sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $Y$ induces a global section of the sheaf $f^*\mathcal F$. The map $H^0(C', i^*(\mathcal{O}_{C'}(1)))\to H^0(C, \mathcal{L})$ is of this form.

Comment: Also, why do you say that $f'$ is birational? It can be a finite map of some degree. For example, consider the map $f:\mathbb P^1\to\mathbb P^1, (x:y)\mapsto (x^2:y^2)$. And of course $f$ is not in general birational, even dimensions of source and target are different.

Comment: Yes indeed, the construction of $f:C \to \mathbb{P}^n _k$ comes with surjective morphism of sheaves $s := (s_0, s_1, ... , s_n): \mathcal{O}_X ^{\oplus n+1} \to \mathcal{L}$ determined by global sections $s_i$, futhermore $dim_k H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)) = n+1$, so I can define $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)) \to H^0(C, \mathcal{L}), e_i \mapsto s_i$ as a surjective morphism between $k$-vector spaces, right? Or do you mean it in another sense? But here occurs the problem why this map is also injective? Do we know $dim_kH^0(C, \mathcal{L})$?

Comment: We take $s_i$ to be a basis, hence they are linearly independent, hence the map is injective.

Comment: The surjectivity of $s$ just implies $dim_kH^0(C, \mathcal{L}) \le n+1$.But why do we know that $dim_kH^0(C, \mathcal{L}) = n+1$?