# Exact Sequence tensoring with Tautological Bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

My question refers to a former theread of mine: [Global Sections of Pullback of Tautological Line Bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708118/global-sections-of-pullback-of-tautological-line-bundle)

Here the setting is the same, so  $C$ is a Gorenstein, integral curve (therefore $1$-dimensional, proper $k$-scheme over a fixed field), $\mathcal{L} \in Pic(C)$ ample, $f: C \to \mathbb{P}^n _k$ a proper morphism induced via $\mathcal{L}:=f^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$ and the image 
$C' := f(C) =  im(f) \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ an integral curve of $\mathbb{P}^n$.

$f$ factorises as $C \xrightarrow{f'} C'  \xrightarrow{\iota} \mathbb{P}^n$. By definition we have $\mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) := \iota^* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$.

I'm trying to get the map

$H^0(C',i^*(\mathbb{P}^n(1)) \to H^0(C,\mathcal{L})$

I have done following attempts: To start with following exact(?) sequence:

$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_{C'} \to f'_*(\mathcal{O}_{C'}) \to \mathcal{F} \to 0$$

Here I just suppose that $\mathcal{O}_{C'} \to f'_*(\mathcal{O}_{C'})$ is injective. Can anybody explain me a concrete argument?

Then it seems seductive to tensor it with $\mathcal{O}_{C'}(1)$, so one gets:

$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) \to f'_*(\mathcal{O}_{C'}) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) \to \mathcal{F}  \to 0$$

The right term stays $\mathcal{F}$ since it's skyscraper, since $f'$ dense.

Here my problem is how to see that $f'_*(\mathcal{O}_{C'}) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) \cong f'_*(\mathcal{L})$ holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some $C$ vs. $C'$ typos currently, but it looks like the thing you're asking about is just the Projection Formula. I'm going to write $g$ instead of $f'.$ We have $$g_*(\mathcal{L}) = g_*(g^*\mathcal{O}_{C'}(1)) \cong g_*(g^*\mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C) \cong \mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) \otimes g_*(\mathcal{O}_C).$$

Comment: How do you get $g_*(g^*\mathcal{O}_{C'}(1)) \cong g_*(g^*\mathcal{O}_{C'} \otimes \mathcal{O}_C) \cong \mathcal{O}_{C'}(1) \otimes g_*(\mathcal{O}_C)$?

Comment: The first isomorphism you point out contained a typo, and should be obvious now. The second is the projection formula. /e Well, they were both affected by the typo. Take another look at the fixed version.